# TLS Mutual Auth: null cert chain (C client -> Java server) unless cafile points to same file as cert

Tags: ssl, openssl, mutual-authentication

I have an issue with the server rejecting the client certificate in the handshake if I issue openssl call with just the cert (with chain) and private key.

This issue goes away if I also set the cafile param and point it to the same file as the cert.

It seems as if openssl cannot construct the chain without the cafile input even if the information is already in the cert input. I wonder if you guys had experience with this. I just find it a bit odd.

To summarize, this works:

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect <ip>:<port> -cert cert_with_chain.pem -key privkey.pem -CAfile cert_with_chain.pem
```

This doesn't work (Server reject with "null cert chain"):

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect <ip>:<port> -cert cert_with_chain.pem -key privkey.pem
```

Open SSL version:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that *"openssl **cannot** construct the chain without the cafile"* but that it wasn't the intention in the first place to do so. The intended behavior is well documented in [man s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/s_client.html):

> -cert certname
>  The **certificate** to use, if one is requested by the server.
>
> -CAfile file
>  A file containing trusted certificates to use during server authentication and to **use when attempting to build the client
>   certificate chain**.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. So does that mean I have to always pass in the CAfile with same input? That seems redundant.

Comment: @user1836155: `-cert` is for the leaf certificate and `-CAfile` for the CA certificates. If you keep both in the same file then you need to use the same file for both options which might seem redundant for you. But if you have these in different files than there is no redundancy at all. Note that `openssl s_client` is just a test tool for somebody who knows what he does - it is not intended as an end-user friendly tool which second guesses what the user might mean.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I use openssl s_client to troubleshoot handshake issue. In my actual service, I use the C API of openssl, though it should be similar in behaviour

Comment: @user1836155: `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` allows you to load both cert and chain at the same time, `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` instead only loads the certificate.

Comment: Hmm... at a glance, our C client only use "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file" instead of SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file". This makes me wonder if there's an issue over at the server side (Java; 3P). I will also take a look at that just in case.

Comment: After checking the packet capture again. We did not indeed send the chain. I did cross reference with a capture with a successful mutual auth with another partner. A difference I see is that the successful handshake has empty distinguished name list whereas the unsuccessful one had hundred or so. I wonder if it can be an inability to find a proper CA

Comment: @user1836155: I think this moves too much out of scope of your original question. If you need help in debugging the problem please ask a new question and provide sufficient context and details there.